# Create C++ Apps in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Windows and I wonder how to create C++ apps in this. 
Actually I have a code in C++ OpenGL (a bowling game I created which you can see in my older posts, that was in Eclipse), that I want to run in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Windows.

Comment: Read the manual? I mean really, what is the question here or is it "Please teach me to use this program, kthxbai."?

Comment: Have you tried File > New > Project > C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a little confusion](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express). If you've got "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8", you cannot make classic C++ projects, only a XAML/C# and C++/CLI managed stuff.

For native C++, try "[Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop#product-express-desktop)" or any commercial distributive.

BTW, AFAIK, you can test [Visual Studio Express 2013 Release Candidate](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads#d-2013-editions) commercial editions free for now.

Comment: "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8" is actually not preventing you to write "native c++" , just limiting you to developing windows store app (and thus using some of the Win32 api and OpenGL).  Windows store app actually don't even allow you to use C++/CLI, just something called C++/CX which are some extension which take some of the syntax of C++/CLI but is actually native. Furthermore even to access WinRT api, you don't even need to use C++/CX if you don't want to, you can see the comment here for more detail: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-532T#c634517976543836549